# Multivariable Taylor series of $f(x,y) = \sin(2x)\sin(y)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

If I have $f(x,y) = \sin(2x)\sin(y)$ and I want to find the Taylor series around $(0,0)$ of $f(x, y)$, how should I do this?

What I've tried is:
$\sin(2x)$ around $x = 0$ is
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{(2x)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}
$$
And $\sin(y)$ around $y = 0$ is
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{y^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}
$$
And so the Taylor series of $f(x,y)$ would simply be
$$
(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{(2x)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!})\cdot(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{y^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!})
$$
But this seems like too simple of a solution and I wouldn't know how to multiply summations, as we haven't covered that yet. I can't find any similar problems in my book either.

Comment: The linear expansion of a two variable function is $f(x,y) = f(a,b) + \partial_xf(a,b)(x-a) + \partial_yf(a,b)(y-b)$

Comment: You do the same thing as in the one variable case but now you take the partial derivatives of each variable

Comment: You could also just take the single variable Taylor series of both functions individually, and expand the product, as you were in the progress of doing.  Just note $$\left(\sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^n\frac{(2x)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\right)\left(\sum_{k\geq 0}(-1)^k\frac{y^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}\right)=\sum_{n,k\geq 0}(-1)^{n+k}\frac{(2x)^{2n+1}y^{2k+1}}{(2n+1)!(2k+1)!}$$ which gives you the two variable Taylor expansion. Though, if you haven't covered this, fair enough.

Comment: @user57 Wouldn't this only be the first order Taylor polynomial of the function? I wasn't given a specific order to calculate so I'd need a general expression

Comment: @C-RAM Is it possible to combinatorically combine the terms such that we can write the sum using just one index? I think that would solve his problem. I am just asking for interest btw.

Comment: Probably (I haven't bothered working this out) the product-to-sum trig identity for a product of two sine functions will help (see [here](http://www.sosmath.com/trig/prodform/prodform.html)). Using this to rewrite your function gives $\frac{1}{2}\left[ \cos(2x-y) - \cos(2x+y)\right].$ My guess is that the similar inputs to cosine and use of binomial expansions (with positive integer exponents) will lead to a manageable general expression. Also of possible interest is [this Mathematics Educator answer](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/18733/745) (e.g. "Problem 3" at the end).

Comment: @Tanamas I'm not quite sure I understand exactly what you mean. Two variable Taylor series are supposed to be of the form $\sum_{n,k\geq 0} a_{n,k}x^ny^k$, rather than being indexed by a single dummy variable. You certainly could use something like a Cauchy product to reduce the double series to a single series summing a sequence of finite sums, but that wouldn't really simplify things at all; in fact, I would argue it's less clear than just taking the product as in my other comment.

Comment: @C-RAM Yes, what you described is what I was referring. Thank you.